# JavaFX Change ScrollPane ViewPort background color

Tags: javafx

I need to change the gray background color of the `ScrollPane` so where you see WHITE and  BOLD  `Labels` i want the background to  be white.

**Image from the Application.**
[image: Screen]

> Code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckMenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioMenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.SeparatorMenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontPosture;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.TextFlow;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainApp extends Application {

    private static final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 800;
    private static final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 200;
    private String family = "Helvetica";
    private TextFlow textFlow = new TextFlow();


    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        HBox hbox = new HBox();

        Group group = getGroup();
        hbox.getChildren().add(group);
        hbox.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);
        hbox.getStyleClass().add("hbox");


        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
        menuBar.prefWidthProperty().bind(stage.widthProperty());
        // File menu - new, save, exit
        Menu fileMenu = new Menu("File");
        MenuItem newMenuItem = new MenuItem("New");
        MenuItem saveMenuItem = new MenuItem("Save");
        MenuItem exitMenuItem = new MenuItem("Exit");
        exitMenuItem.setOnAction(actionEvent -> Platform.exit());

        fileMenu.getItems().addAll(newMenuItem, saveMenuItem,
                new SeparatorMenuItem(), exitMenuItem);

        Menu webMenu = new Menu("Web");
        CheckMenuItem htmlMenuItem = new CheckMenuItem("HTML");
        htmlMenuItem.setSelected(true);
        webMenu.getItems().add(htmlMenuItem);

        CheckMenuItem cssMenuItem = new CheckMenuItem("CSS");
        cssMenuItem.setSelected(true);
        webMenu.getItems().add(cssMenuItem);

        Menu sqlMenu = new Menu("SQL");
        ToggleGroup tGroup = new ToggleGroup();
        RadioMenuItem mysqlItem = new RadioMenuItem("MySQL");
        mysqlItem.setToggleGroup(tGroup);

        RadioMenuItem oracleItem = new RadioMenuItem("Oracle");
        oracleItem.setToggleGroup(tGroup);
        oracleItem.setSelected(true);

        sqlMenu.getItems().addAll(mysqlItem, oracleItem,
                new SeparatorMenuItem());

        Menu tutorialManu = new Menu("Tutorial");
        tutorialManu.getItems().addAll(
                new CheckMenuItem("Java"),
                new CheckMenuItem("JavaFX"),
                new CheckMenuItem("Swing"));

        sqlMenu.getItems().add(tutorialManu);

        menuBar.getMenus().addAll(fileMenu, webMenu, sqlMenu);


        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(hbox);
        scrollPane.setFitToHeight(true);
        scrollPane.setHbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);
        scrollPane.setVbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.ALWAYS);

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(scrollPane);

        root.setPadding(new Insets(15));
        root.setTop(menuBar);
        //root.setCenter(hbox);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        //scene.getStylesheets().add("layoutstyle.css");
        stage.setTitle("Dummy Title");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        Text text3 = new Text("\nDummy text");
        text3.setFont(Font.font(family, 22));
        textFlow.getChildren().add(text3);
    }

    private Group getGroup(){
        double size = 50;

        textFlow = new TextFlow();
        textFlow.setLayoutX(40);
        textFlow.setLayoutY(40);
        Text text1 = new Text("White");
        text1.setFont(Font.font(family, size));
        text1.setFill(Color.RED);
        Text text2 = new Text("\nBold");
        text2.setFill(Color.ORANGE);
        text2.setFont(Font.font(family, FontWeight.BOLD, size));
        Text text3 = new Text("\n World");
        text3.setFill(Color.GREEN);
        text3.setFont(Font.font(family, FontPosture.ITALIC, size));
        textFlow.getChildren().addAll(text1, text2, text3);

        return new Group(textFlow);

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a simplification of your real code? You have lot of nested nodes that seem unnecessary (a `TextFlow` as the only child of a `Group`, which is the only child of a `HBox`, which is in a `ScrollPane` which is in a `BorderPane`). It seems you could get rid of the `Group` and the `HBox` entirely.

Comment: Please, i mean it be more specific and reduce the code so we can add a minimal answer... :) What that means?`Basically I desired to change the gray background color where you see WHITE, BOLD to white.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to modify the `.viewport` color of the `ScrollPane` with css:

[image]

CSS code:

```
/*The ViewPort of the ScrollPane */
.scroll-pane .viewport {
    -fx-background-color: white; /*or whatever you want*/
  }

.scroll-pane {
    -fx-background-color:transparent;
}
```

And change these lines of code from your application:

```
 //........

 //.........  
 root.setPadding(new Insets(15));
        root.setTop(menuBar);
        //root.setCenter(hbox);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        stage.setTitle("Dummy Title");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

   //........

  //.........
```

**Finally** mention that the css file which contains the css code,in this example has to be in the same source folder as the Application.java file.

[image]

Comment: Please how do I apply your solution to the problem?

Comment: @Armel i have completely reedited the answer so it does what you need.The `key` here is that you are asking for the `ViewPort` of the `ScrollPane`

Comment: @Armel Actually i had some kind of same question before some months,and someone told me the answer,so you know that's how it works :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess your question is, how to apply a white background?

via css-style (an entry in your css-File would be better for that):

```
root.setStyle("-fx-background-color:white");
menuBar.styleProperty().bind(root.styleProperty());
```

via api

```
Background background = new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.WHITE, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY));
root.setBackground(background);
menuBar.setBackground(background);
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I have applied your solution, indeed the background is white however, the area where you see the text WHITE, BOLD is still gray and not white color background. Any more ideas?